# Autoware.auto autonomous driving with simulator

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does autoware.auto currently support autonomous driving with simulator such as LGSVL?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381461/autoware.auto-autonomous-driving-with-simulator/) by [meng100](https://answers.ros.org/users/67304/meng100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what you mean by "autonomous driving" but Autoware.Auto certainly supports the LGSVL simulator https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html
and currently autonomous parking https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/avpdemo.html#avpdemo-simulation

We are in the process of adding more general autonomous-driving capabilities to the stack, and those, too, will be testable with the same simulator

---

Originally posted by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) with karma: 131 on 2021-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meng100](https://answers.ros.org/users/67304/meng100/) on 2021-07-01**:
Thanks for your reply!  I just now tried to follow the [autonomous parking tutorial](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/avpdemo.html#avpdemo-simulation) that you shared, but I was unable to initialize the localization using `2D Pose Esmiate`, nothing happened after I drew the green arrow. Do you know why is that so?

**Comment by [meng100](https://answers.ros.org/users/67304/meng100/) on 2021-07-01**:
After another hour of trying, it suddenly worked.. thanks anyway!